# How to build a Dynamic SELECT Query in Mule 4 to get data from Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, mulesoft, mule4

I have a requirement to build a dynamic SELECT query which has to take any select number of attributes, any table name and any number of where conditions like a sample query hown below. The values in {} will be dynamic.

`select {first_name,last_name} from {tableName} where {student_id=12345 and status='active'}`

if first_name,last_name are not present, then it will be all (select * from). Where condition also may be empty.

I am thinking maybe I can handle the inputs to my API as below

`{first_name,last_name} - payload {tableName} -  uri param {student_id=12345&status=active}- query params`

rest endpoint will look like this – (POST) with input payload as shown below

`http://**************/{tableName}?student_id=12345&status=active`

input payload
`{ param1:first_name, param2 : last_name }`

Also planning to add table names in property file and map them to variable tableName based on the incoming path or a parameter to avoid security breaches.

Could you please suggest if this is the right approach? Want to avoid any security breaches and also want to make it more generic API for reusability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my suggestions for your requirement. Ideally, you should follow the guidelines of RESTful API design

1. Since it is a select query, the method should be GET, and the fields (columns) to be retrieved can be defined in the query parameter. You can use the **"fields"** parameter to restrict the set of properties returned to only those that you explicitly specify, and it should be specified as a comma-separated list. For example, to return only the firstName and lastName fields for all records in the database, use

> GET /students?fields=firstName,lastName

2. If the URLs (endpoints) of the API replicate the table names, there is no need to manage the table names in the property files. However, be mindful to follow the naming conventions for the endpoints. Use nouns instead of verbs and use plural nouns. For example

> GET /students or /customers

3. If there is any primary key from the database, it should be defined as a URI parameter, and the rest of the filtering conditions can be defined in the query parameter **"q"**. This parameter can be used for specifying a filter expression that restricts the set of items returned, based on criteria such as numeric comparisons or string matching. For example

> GET /students/{studentId}?q=status = 'active' and name = 'xyz'

4. Eventually, the number of records in the database may increase, and the response will become too large. Therefore, it is advised to implement the pagination mechanism as well.

Comment: Thanks Jarus, Are you suggesting we can add fileds and the filtering conditions like below
GET /students/{studentId}?fields=firstName,lastName and q=status = 'active' and name = 'xyz'

As in my case both fields and filtering conditions are dynamic.

Comment: Yes, of course you can do that. But please ensure that the filtering expressions are included in the "q" query parameter. You may refer the link(https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/cx-commerce/21b/ccdev/rest-api-query-parameters.html) for more information